# Retrieve video ID from YouTube link

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I want the YouTube video ID from this link (`VgC4b9K-gYU`):

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgC4b9K-gYU
```

How would I get it using Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use 'urlparse' library.

Python2

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgC4b9K-gYU"
>>> url_parsed = urlparse.urlsplit(url)
>>> qsl = urlparse.parse_qs(url_parsed.query)
>>> qsl
{'v': ['VgC4b9K-gYU']}
```

Python3

```
from urllib import parse
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgC4b9K-gYU"
url_parsed = parse.urlparse(url)
qsl = parse.parse_qs(url_parsed.query)
```

Comment: I'm getting `'function' object has no attribute 'urlsplit'` error - any idea? I've imported: `from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlsplit, parse_qs`

Comment: which python version you are usin? This code is for v2

Comment: I'm using Version 3.5

Comment: Thanks. Could you also tell me how I can get the domain name (e.g. `youtube.com` from `"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgC4b9K-gYU"` ?

Comment: you can use `url_parsed.netloc`. Also, check this docs, you'll find more helpfull https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Answer (score 0):

There may be more ways to do it but i will prefer [urlparser library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/urlparse3/) to do this.

**Try this:**

```
import urlparse3

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgC4b9K-gYU'
parsed_url = urlparse3.parse_url(url)
print parsed_url.query # Ordered-Dictionary

for k, v in parsed_url.query.items():
    print 'The Key you want is : ' + v
```

**Output:**

```
The Key you want is : VgC4b9K-gYU
```

Hope this will help you. Thankyou! :)